# Android/Firefox: event.keycode returns Undefined on keyup

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, firefox, keyup

I have one website application having a search bar. The Search bar is working fine in all other browsers except Firefox on Android device.

I have alerted the `keyCode` and getting Undefined for every key.

Below is the code I have used.

```
domReady(function()
{
  var is_android = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("android") > -1;
  var is_firefox = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('firefox') > -1;

  if( is_firefox && is_android )
  {
    $('#search, #support-search').bind('input keyup', __search );
  }
  else
  {
    $('#search, #support-search').on( 'keyup', __search );
  }

}

var __search = function( event )
{
  var kc = event.which || event.keyCode;
  alert("KC:"+kc);
  alert("event.keyCode:"+event.keyCode);
}
```

Both alerts showing Undefined.

Please let me know what's going wrong here.

Comment: Your condition forcing android and firefox to use `bind()` makes no sense. `on()` should be used in all cases. The `domReady()` function can be made a one-liner which attaches the event.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, actually the main problem was on(). It was not working and there was no alert of keycode. So, forced android/firefox to use bind(). After that getting the Undefined in the alert.

Comment: You shouldn't need to use `keyCode`. The `which` property works fine. `bind()` has been deprecated now, so you really should not be using it.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, Thanks for letting me know bind() is deprecated. I was really unknown about it. Also, I will try to use `which` to detect key pressed. Thanks.

Comment: Instead using `bind()` I have used the line `$('#search, #support-search').on( 'input keyup', __search );` that resolved the issue of `keyup` event. And use of `which` returning me `0` instead Undefined that is useful to compare key.

Comment: Pretty much what my first comment said :) I added it as an answer for you

Answer (score 0):

Your condition forcing Android and Firefox to use `bind()` makes very little sense. `on()` should be used in all cases. The `domReady()` function can be made a one-liner which attaches the event, like this:

```js
domReady(function()
  $('#search, #support-search').on('input keyup', __search);
}

var __search = function(e) {
  var kc = e.which || e.keyCode;
  console.log("KC:" + kc);
  console.log("event.keyCode:" + e.keyCode);
}
```

Also note the use of `console.log()` over `alert()` for debugging. Avoid using `alert()` as it coerces data types, so what you see may not be the actual value.